# Мусор в начале строки при чтении из текстового файла

Tags: c++

Считываю из файла текст следующим способом:

```
while (!inputFile.eof()) 
        inputFile>>code[index++];
```

Первым тремя считанными символами являются `п»ї`, хотя в тексте их нет. Почему так происходит?

**UPD**

Попробовал так:

```
getline(inputFile,code,'\0');
```

но эффект тот же.

Comment: Что такое `code`?

Comment: @AnT code - переменная типа string

Comment: Ну и как обычно: цикл с предусловием `!eof` - практически всегда ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это так называемый Byte Order Mark (BOM). Заголовок вставляемый в начало текстового файла, в котором указан тип Юникода. Практически все современные текстовые редакторы его поддерживают и достаточно часто вставляют.

> .. специальный символ из стандарта Юникод, вставляемый в начало текстового файла или потока для обозначения того, что в файле (потоке) используется Юникод, а также для косвенного указания кодировки и порядка байтов, с помощью которых символы Юникода были закодированы.

Вики - [Маркер последовательности байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: это как-то можно обойти? или нужно считывать всю строку и потом из нее вырезать подстроку?

Comment: Это нужно не обходить, а использовать. Вы читаете текст побайтово, и символы Юникода тоже будете читать побайтово и получать мусор, вместо, например, русского текста или других символов не входящих в ANSI. Так что либо читайте по байтам и игнорируйте этот заголовок, либо обрабатывайте Юникодные тексты (с учетом возможных форматов), а лучше читайте текст библиотечными методами.

Comment: библиотечные методы - это какие?

Comment: Тут я вам не подскажу, я не Сишник. В Делфе - это чтение через TStringList, например, с указанием кодировки, либо автоопределением (которое как раз на заголовки смотрит, и при чтении приводит в UTF16 емнип). Запись соответственно так же, с указанием кодировки.